# Most efficient way of creating and exporting animations

Tags: export, animation

I have been creating animations in two different ways: 1)using `Animate` 2)using `Table` to create a list of plots at different times.

1)Let's start with `Animate`. The function I want to animate is the following

```
ψTimeDep[x_, r_, ϕ_, α_, t_] := 
 1/Sqrt[Cosh[r]]*((m ω)/(π h))^(1/4) *
  Exp[-((m ω)/(2 h))*x^2 - 
    Conjugate[α]/
     2 (α + Conjugate[α] E^(I ϕ)*Tanh[r]) - 
    I*ω*t - (m ω)/h E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]*
     E^(-2*I*ω*t)*
     x^2 + (α + Conjugate[α] E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r])*
     E^(-I*ω*t)*Sqrt[(2 m ω)/h] x - 
    1/2*(E^(-I*ω*
         t)*(α + Conjugate[α] E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]) - 
       E^(-2*I*ω*t)*Sqrt[(2 m ω)/h] E^(I ϕ)
         Tanh[r] x)^2 - 
    Log[1 - E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*ω*t)]/
    2 - ((E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*ω*t))/(
      1 - E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*ω*t))) *1/
     2*(E^(-I*ω*
         t)*(α + Conjugate[α] E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]) - 
       E^(-2*I*ω*t)*Sqrt[(2 m ω)/h] E^(I ϕ)
         Tanh[r] x)^2]
```

It is a pretty complicated function, but the thing I'm interested in plotting for now is `ψTimeDep[x,-3,0,0,t]`. When I run

```
animation1 = 
 Animate[Plot[Re[ψTimeDep[x, -3, 0, 0, t]], {x, -100, 100}, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.3, 0.3}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0042], Blue}, 
   Axes -> {False, False}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], FrameTicks -> LinTicks, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 20], Frame -> True,
    PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[Framed[LineLegend[{Automatic}, {"r=0,α=0"}]], 
     ImageScaled[{0.8, 0.9}]]], {t, 0, 6, 0.01}, 
  AnimationRate -> 0.15, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

it animates the plot quickly. However, the problem is that when I try to export it as a .swf file I cannot play it on my computer (I have already asked this in another forum), but more importantly [Flash Player will be disabled on December 31st, 2020](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html), so exporting to .swf file is not a good long-term solution.

2)Next, I can create a list of plots at different times using `Table`, as mentioned [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/465460), and export them as a gif. Following the advice of this post I created the following code

```
animation3 = 
  Table[Plot[Re[ψTimeDep[x, -3, 0, 0, t]], {x, -100, 100}, 
    PlotRange -> {-0.3, 0.3}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0042], Blue}, 
    Axes -> {False, False},
     Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 100, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[Framed[LineLegend[{Automatic}, {"r=-3,α=0"}]], 
      ImageScaled[{0.8, 0.9}]]], {t, 0, 8, 0.1}];
```

This solution works, but it takes a lot of time to run this piece of code (my computer is 6 years old). I had to remove the `FrameTicks`, `FrameStyle`, `FrameTicksStyle` options to make it run in a considerable amount of time.

I have been using option 2), but I would really like to reduce the amount of time it takes to create my animation. Does anybody know any other way I can create an animation and exporting it in the least possible amount of time?

**EDIT:** I set `ω=1`, `m=1` and `h=1`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `:=` by `=` and define a new `f`.

```
Clear["`*"];
f[x_, t_] = 
 1/Sqrt[Cosh[r]]*((m ω)/(π h))^(1/4)*
    Exp[-((m ω)/(2 h))*x^2 - 
      Conjugate[α]/
        2 (α + Conjugate[α] E^(I ϕ)*Tanh[r]) - 
      I*ω*t - (m ω)/h E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]*
       E^(-2*I*ω*t)*
       x^2 + (α + Conjugate[α] E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r])*
       E^(-I*ω*t)*Sqrt[(2 m ω)/h] x - 
      1/2*(E^(-I*ω*t)*(α + 
             Conjugate[α] E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]) - 
          E^(-2*I*ω*t)*
           Sqrt[(2 m ω)/h] E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r] x)^2 - 
      Log[1 - E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*ω*t)]/
       2 - ((E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*ω*t))/(1 - 
           E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*ω*t)))*1/
        2*(E^(-I*ω*t)*(α + 
             Conjugate[α] E^(I ϕ) Tanh[r]) - 
          E^(-2*I*ω*t)*
           Sqrt[(2 m ω)/h] E^(I ϕ) Tanh[
            r] x)^2] /. {r -> -3, ϕ -> 0, α -> 0, m -> 1, 
    h -> 1, ω -> 1} // Re
animation1 = 
 Animate[Plot[f[x, t], {x, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> {-0.3, 0.3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0042], Blue}, Axes -> {False, False}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 20], Frame -> True,
    PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[Framed[LineLegend[{Automatic}, {"r=0,α=0"}]], 
     ImageScaled[{0.8, 0.9}]]], {t, 0, 6, 0.01}, 
  AnimationRate -> 0.15, AnimationRunning -> False]
(*
animation3 = 
 Table[Plot[f[x,t], {x, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> {-0.3, 0.3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0042], Blue}, Axes -> {False, False}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[Framed[LineLegend[{Automatic}, {"r=-3,α=0"}]], 
     ImageScaled[{0.8, 0.9}]]], {t, 0, 8, 0.1}] *)
```

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: It takes less time, but still it is very slow compared to `Animate`. Is this the best it can do?